VirtualService and DestinationRule Not behaving As per rules set in ISTIO
In ISTIO VirtualService and DestinationRule Not behaving properly, find the manifest below,
when trying to curl my service its distributing traffic to both v1 and v2 pod even after mentioning v1 only in virtual service
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-v1
  namespace: istio
  labels:
    app: nginx
    version: v1
spec:
  selector: 
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx 
      version: v1 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx 
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: chaitanya305/good-morning
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-v2
  namespace: istio
  labels:
    app: nginx
    version: v2
spec:
  selector: 
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx 
      version: v2 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx 
        version: v2
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: chaitanya305/good-night
          ports:
          - containerPort: 80

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-svc
  namespace: istio
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 30080
  type: NodePort


---

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: my-virtualservice
  namespace: istio
spec:
  hosts:
    - nginx-svc.istio.svc.cluster.local
  http:
    - route:
        - destination:
            host: nginx-svc.istio.svc.cluster.local
            subset: v1

---

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: my-destinationrule
  namespace: istio
spec:
  host: nginx-svc.istio.svc.cluster.local
  subsets:
    - name: v1
      labels:
        version: v1
    - name: v2
      labels:
        version: v2

When i try to acces below url
curl nginx-svc.istio.cluster.local
traffic goes to both v1 and v2 pod, as per virtual service rule it suppose to go to v1 only. which is suppose to provide output as Hi good morning only.
root@jenkins-deployment-f4d955ff4-kpxgj:/tmp# cat bash2.sh
while true
do
curl nginx-svc.istio.svc.cluster.local
sleep 2
done
root@jenkins-deployment-f4d955ff4-kpxgj:/tmp#  ./bash2.sh
 Hi good morning 
 good Night sweet dreams 
 Hi good morning 
 Hi good morning 
 Hi good morning 
 good Night sweet dreams
 good Night sweet dreams 
 Hi good morning 

^Croot@jenkins-deployment-f4d955ff4-kpxgj:/tmp#

Hello, how are you validating traffic ? Meaning, can you post some findings where you got that traffic indeed went to second deployment ?

Yes sure, I am trying to curl my nginx-svc form one of other pod in my cluster, as per virtual service rule it suppose to go to v1 pod only which is prints hi good morning. but it going to both pods,
I have updated the question with curl output which shows traffic goes to v2 as well.

The pod you are running the curl command should have istio-proxy sidecar. The rules are considered only in the source pod. So the source pod needs the proxy sidecar. This will also work if you don't have proxies for the nginx-v1 and nginx-v2 deployments. Although the requests will be plaintext.

Thanks, it worked when try to curl form pod having istio-proxy container.

Can you please help to know how can we make it work through gateway, i have deployed gateway and httproute resource as it created pod with one container in it which is istio-proxy.
Now when I try to access nginx-gateway-istio svc it again sent to both pods.

k get pods -n istio
NAME                                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-demo-77f7d45d4f-nzhqj           2/2     Running   0          49m
nginx-gateway-istio-588df78c4-lpph4   1/1     Running   0          35m
nginx-v1-64f7c7d769-4jc8g             2/2     Running   0          49m
nginx-v2-6d94567d9d-r49wq             2/2     Running   0          49m

controlplane $ k get svc -n istio
NAME                  TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
nginx-gateway-istio   NodePort   10.109.128.26         15021:32314/TCP,80:32040/TCP   38m
nginx-svc             NodePort   10.97.162.190           80:30080/TCP                   49m

To understand all these, atleast i would need to know all the CRs you used.
Alternatively you can use istio-ingress (https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-control/) as well. This is deviating from the original thread, so it should be in a separate question.
